# Looking for an automation tool with rich UI view of test execution reports

Tags: automation, automated-tests, reporting

My team is migrating from manual to automation testing. Our first issue is that we cannot find any tool which satisfy our need in **generating visual and in-depth execution report**.

We really need your help to find out a tool providing detailed test reports and can be analyzed to visualize test execution status, performance, and flakiness in different ways.

Comment: Off topic in SO..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My team have used several tools: Selenium, TestNG, Robot Framework & Katalon Studio. So from my own experience, I think the nearest tool that we used - Katalon can help you. Their native reports provide the "snapshot" information of each execution session with intuitive charts & graphs.
You can identify easily particular issues with flaky analysis on your test executions that visualization. And of course, it's available for free usage.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, Lucas. I have heard about Katalon too but didn't used that. This time my team will try it out. Hope they can satisfy our demand in visual execution reports!

Answer (score 1):

My team is using Katalon analytics, it has a lot of useful features and it's free. I have just begun to use it and I think it's quite good at making detailed reports. You should try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late response to the post.
But still, if someone in need of a good test automation dashboard based on just few api calls, Ares dashboards (From ZenQ team) is a much better option to try and its completely free.

ARES, is an acronym for Test Automation Results dashboard. It's a TestAutomation framework/tool agonistic solution, that simplifies the collection of Test automation results and their analysis via live dashboard, daily/weekly trends, frequent failures etc.
Website: http://www.testastra.com/

Below repo has some code samples, documentation and usage of ARES test automation dashboard:
https://github.com/testastra/ARES

Answer (score 0):

My team is using https://github.com/last-hit-aab/last-hit for UI automation test, this tool is powerful, can record and replay without script change .

Comment: when you using katalon , the testing team need change 30% script for test case run